# Using Checkbox with recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am having trouble with **recyclerview** with check boxes.
  I am using a recycler view that has **check boxes**. Now the titles with checked check boxes should appear in my activity. I have added the check box selected title in the **array list** how do I get them in the activity? 
 I just need the checked check boxes array list in my activity.

below is my adapter class

```
   public class CheckboxAdapter extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckboxAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<SearchListItem> searchListItems;
        private OnSearchItemSelected onSearchItemSelected;
        public ArrayList<String> addTitle;

        CheckboxAdapter(List<SearchListItem> arrayList, OnSearchItemSelected onSearchItemSelected) {
            this.searchListItems = arrayList;
            this.onSearchItemSelected = onSearchItemSelected;

        }


        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            @BindView(R.id.title)
            TextView mTxtTitle;
            @BindView(R.id.checkBox)
            CheckBox checkBox;

            ViewHolder(View row) {
                super(row);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, row);

                row.setOnClickListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                SearchListItem searchListItem = searchListItems.get(pos);
                try {
                    onSearchItemSelected.onClick(pos, searchListItem);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return searchListItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CheckboxAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            SearchListItem output = searchListItems.get(position);
            holder.mTxtTitle.setText(output.title);

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                        addAllTitle(holder);
                    }
                    }
                });
            }

        public OnSearchItemSelected getOnSearchItemSelected() {
            return onSearchItemSelected;
        }



        public void addAllTitle(ViewHolder holder) {
            for (int i = 0; i < addTitle.size(); i++) {
                addTitle.add(String.valueOf(holder.mTxtTitle));
            }
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CheckboxAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_checkbox, parent, false);

            return new CheckboxAdapter.ViewHolder(contactView);
        }
}
```

Comment: you can use interface to do it, you can look for an example here 

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022

Answer (score 0):

you have to add one `boolean` in your model class such as `isChecked`

make it `true` if `checkBox` is checked else `false`

get same list which is passed in `activity` to `adapter`, this list will give you all checked boxes

for ex
 in `activity`

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(myList);

/*you can get all checked boxes here, paste this code where you need it*/
    for(i=0; i<myList.size();i++){
        if(myList.isChecked()){
            //... do somehing ...
        }
    }
```

in `adapter`

```
onBindViewHolder() method



holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                 myList.setchecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how will i  get (mylist.isChecked)?

Comment: you have to add one `boolean`  in your model class such as `isChecked` and make it's getter setter methods